# Unable to autofill tabs of website through excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

[image]

I have managed to create the below code, but I'm unable to autofill the fields marked with red arrows shown in the image, as there is no ID available for them in the HTML code.

All the tabs shown in image does not have IDs.

What should be the coding for filling these ?

````
Sub TDS_Autofill()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document
doc.parentWindow.execScript "sendRequest(281)", "JavaScript"

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("m2").Value = "Company" 
Then
doc.getElementById("0020").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("m2").Value = "Non 
Company" Then
doc.getElementById("0021").Click
End If



If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("o2").Value = "(200) 
TDS/TCS Payable by Taxpayer" Then
doc.getElementById("200").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("o2").Value = "(400) 
TDS/TCS Regular Assessment" Then
doc.getElementById("400").Click
End If


IE.document.querySelector("select.form-control").selectedIndex = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("r2").Value


doc.getElementById("NetBanking").Click

doc.getElementById("NetBank_Name_c").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan 
AutoFill").Range("t2").Value



End Sub```
````

Comment: It is a jsp, so it is Java. You won´t find any variable there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the inputs using their names by `doc.getElementsByName`. It returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name. Then you should find out the index number of the element you want.

[image]

For example, you can set the value of "Tax Deduction Account No" using the following code:

```
doc.getElementsByName("TAN")(1).Value = "abc"
```

For the other inputs, you could use the same methods. I make a test with setting some of the values and you can see the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByTag("input") that returns a collection of components that you can access with an index, and then set their value to what you need.

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).value = "My value"
```